# List Comprehension but on list selected for iteration based on condition

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am having two lists `list1` and `list2` as:

```
list1 = [4, 3, 20, 10]
list2 = ['a', 'f', 'd', 'b']
```

I want to create a new list `result` based on the condition that if my condition `num==10` is `True`, then `result` should be holding the content from `list1` else it should be holding the content from `list2`. Below is the code I tried:

```
num = 10
result = [element for element in list1 if num == 10 else list2]
```

But this is raising `SyntaxError`. How should I achieve this?

Expected output for above code is:

```
[4, 3, 20, 10]  # stored in `result`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to create a new list `result` based on your condition `num==10`, you may simply do *(no need of list comprehension)*:

```
>>> result = (list2, list1)[num==10]
>>> result
[4, 3, 20, 10]
```

Above result is based on the fact that Python treats boolean value `True` and `False` as `1` and `0` respectively. So, we are fetching the desired list from tuple based on the condition.

**Other alternatives** to perform the same task:

```
# Alternative 1: Using your `if`/`else` logic
result = (list1 if num == 10 else list2)

# Alternative 2: using `and`/`or` logic
result = (num == 10 and list1) or list2
```

**If list comprehension is must** to use for you (may be to perform some operation on the elements), then you may use *list comprehension* with any of the above condition as:

```
>>> num = 10
>>> list1 = [4, 3, 20, 10]
>>> list2 = ['a', 'f', 'd', 'b']

# Using tuple of lists with boolean index
>>> result = [element for element in (list2, list1)[num==10]]
>>> result
[4, 3, 20, 10]

# Using `if`/`else` logic
>>> result = [element for element in (list1 if num == 10 else list2)]
>>> result
[4, 3, 20, 10]

# Using using `and`/`or` logic
>>> result = [element for element in (num == 10 and list1) or list2]
>>> result
[4, 3, 20, 10]
```

Answer (score 5):

You're just missing some parentheses:

```
result = [element for element in (list1 if num == 10 else list2)]
```

A list comprehension can have a filtering condition (`comp_if` in [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)) as follows:

```
[a for a in b if c]
```

In your current version, `list1` is `b` and `num == 10` is `c`, but your additional `else list2` is syntactically invalid.

You need to be explicit that your conditional expression is all part of `b`, which you can do with parentheses.

Comment: That's it.
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Maryam no worries, note https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers